# Spring Boot UserDetails returning me null

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I'm creating a simple login page using spring boot and security.
However after creating user, when I try to log in, i see the entity "staff" is a null hence producing the error Invalid Login.

SecurityConfig.java

```
    package com.ridzuan.service.StaffServiceImpl;

    import java.util.Set;

    import org.slf4j.Logger;
    import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
    import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

    import com.ridzuan.dao.RoleDao;
    import com.ridzuan.dao.StaffDao;
    import com.ridzuan.domain.Staff;
    import com.ridzuan.domain.security.StaffRole;
    import com.ridzuan.service.StaffService;

   @Service
   public class StaffServiceImpl implements StaffService{

private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StaffService.class);

@Autowired
private StaffDao staffDao;

@Autowired
private RoleDao roleDao;

@Autowired
private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

public void save(Staff staff) {
    staffDao.save(staff);
}

public Staff findByNric(String nric) {
    return staffDao.findByNric(nric);
}

public boolean checkStaffExists(String nric) {
    if (findByNric(nric) != null) return true;
    else return false;
}

@Transactional
public Staff createStaff(Staff staff, Set<StaffRole> staffRoles) {
    Staff localStaff = staffDao.findByNric(staff.getNric());

    if(localStaff != null) {
        LOG.info("Staff with nric {} already exist.", staff.getNric());
    }else {
        String encryptedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(staff.getPassword());
        staff.setPassword(encryptedPassword);

        for(StaffRole sr : staffRoles) {
            roleDao.save(sr.getRole());
        }

        staff.getStaffRoles().addAll(staffRoles);

        localStaff = staffDao.save(staff);
    }

    return localStaff;
}

}
```

HomeController.java

```
package com.ridzuan.controller;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.ridzuan.dao.RoleDao;
import com.ridzuan.domain.Staff;
import com.ridzuan.domain.security.StaffRole;
import com.ridzuan.service.StaffService;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

@Autowired
public StaffService staffService;

@Autowired
private RoleDao roleDao;

@RequestMapping("/")
public String home() {
    return "redirect:/index";
}

@RequestMapping("/index")
public String index() {
    return "index";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String register(Model model) {
    Staff staff = new Staff();

    model.addAttribute("staff", staff);

    return "register";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String registerPost(@ModelAttribute("staff") Staff staff, Model model) {

    if(staffService.checkStaffExists(staff.getNric())) {
        model.addAttribute("staffExists", true);

        return "register";
    }else {
        Set <StaffRole> staffRoles = new HashSet<>();
        staffRoles.add(new StaffRole(staff, roleDao.findByName("ROLE_STAFF")));

        staffService.createStaff(staff, staffRoles);


        return "redirect:/";
    }

}
}
```

RoleDao.java

```
package com.ridzuan.dao;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import com.ridzuan.domain.security.Role;

public interface RoleDao extends CrudRepository<Role, Integer>{
    Role findByName(String name);
}
```

StaffDao.java

```
package com.ridzuan.dao;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import com.ridzuan.domain.Staff;

public interface StaffDao extends CrudRepository<Staff, Long>{

    Staff findByNric(String nric);
}
```

Authority.java

```
package com.ridzuan.domain.security;

import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;

/**
* Created by z00382545 on 10/20/16.
 */
public class Authority implements GrantedAuthority{

private final String authority;

public Authority(String authority) {
    this.authority = authority;
}

@Override
public String getAuthority() {
    return authority;
}
}
```

Role.java

```
package com.ridzuan.domain.security;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * Created by z00382545 on 10/20/16.
 */

@Entity
public class Role {
@Id
//    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int roleId;

private String name;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "role", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<StaffRole> staffRoles = new HashSet<>();

public Role() {

}

public int getRoleId() {
    return roleId;
}

public void setRoleId(int roleId) {
    this.roleId = roleId;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Set<StaffRole> getStaffRoles() {
    return staffRoles;
}

public void setStaffRoles(Set<StaffRole> staffRoles) {
    this.staffRoles = staffRoles;
}


}
```

StaffRole.java

```
package com.ridzuan.domain.security;

import com.ridzuan.domain.Staff;

import javax.persistence.*;

/**
 * Created by z00382545 on 10/20/16.
 */

@Entity
@Table(name="staff_role")
public class StaffRole {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long staffRoleId;

public StaffRole(Staff staff, Role role) {
    this.staff = staff;
    this.role = role;
}


@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "userId")
private Staff staff;


@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "roleId")
private Role role;

public StaffRole() {}

public long getStaffRoleId() {
    return staffRoleId;
}

public void setStaffRoleId(long staffRoleId) {
    this.staffRoleId = staffRoleId;
}

public Staff getStaff() {
    return staff;
}

public void setStaff(Staff staff) {
    this.staff = staff;
}

public Role getRole() {
    return role;
}

public void setRole(Role role) {
    this.role = role;
}


}
```

Off.java

```
package com.ridzuan.domain;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

@Entity
public class Off {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long idOff;
private Date startDate;
private Date endDate;
private String remarks;
private boolean isApproved;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "userId")
private Staff staff;

public long getIdOff() {
    return idOff;
}

public void setId(long idOff) {
    this.idOff = idOff;
}

public Date getStartDate() {
    return startDate;
}

public void setStartDate(Date startDate) {
    this.startDate = startDate;
}

public Date getEndDate() {
    return endDate;
}

public void setEndDate(Date endDate) {
    this.endDate = endDate;
}

public String getRemarks() {
    return remarks;
}

public void setRemarks(String remarks) {
    this.remarks = remarks;
}

public boolean isApproved() {
    return isApproved;
}

public void setApproved(boolean isApproved) {
    this.isApproved = isApproved;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Leave [idOff=" + idOff + ", startDate=" + startDate + ", endDate=" + endDate + ", remarks=" + remarks
            + ", isApproved=" + isApproved + "]";
}

}
```

Staff.java

```
package com.ridzuan.domain;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.ridzuan.domain.security.Authority;
import com.ridzuan.domain.security.StaffRole;

@Entity
public class Staff implements UserDetails {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "userId", nullable = false, updatable = false)
private long userId;
private String nric;
private int phone;
private String password;
private boolean isActive = true;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "staff", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JsonIgnore
private List<Off> offList;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "staff", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JsonIgnore
private Set<StaffRole> staffRoles = new HashSet<>();

public Set<StaffRole> getStaffRoles() {
    return staffRoles;
}

public void setStaffRoles(Set<StaffRole> staffRoles) {
    this.staffRoles = staffRoles;
}

public String getNric() {
    return nric;
}

public void setNric(String nric) {
    this.nric = nric;
}

public long getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public List<Off> getOffList() {
    return offList;
}

public void setOffList(List<Off> offList) {
    this.offList = offList;
}

public void setUserId(long userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

public int getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public void setPhone(int phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}

public boolean isActive() {
    return isActive;
}

public void setActive(boolean isActive) {
    this.isActive = isActive;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {

    Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<>();
    staffRoles.forEach(sr -> authorities.add(new Authority(sr.getRole().getName())));       

    return authorities;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public String getUsername() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

}
```

StaffSecurityService.java

```
package com.ridzuan.service.StaffServiceImpl;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.ridzuan.dao.StaffDao;
import com.ridzuan.domain.Staff;

@Service
public class StaffSecurityService implements UserDetailsService {

private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StaffSecurityService.class);

@Autowired
private StaffDao staffDao;

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String nric) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    Staff staff = staffDao.findByNric(nric);
    LOG.info("NRIC {}, nric");
    if(null == staff) {
        LOG.warn("NRIC {} not found", nric);
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("NRIC: " + nric + " not found!");
    }

    return staff;
}
}
```

StaffServiceImpl.java

```
package com.ridzuan.service.StaffServiceImpl;

import java.util.Set;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.ridzuan.dao.RoleDao;
import com.ridzuan.dao.StaffDao;
import com.ridzuan.domain.Staff;
import com.ridzuan.domain.security.StaffRole;
import com.ridzuan.service.StaffService;

@Service
public class StaffServiceImpl implements StaffService{

private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StaffService.class);

@Autowired
private StaffDao staffDao;

@Autowired
private RoleDao roleDao;

@Autowired
private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

public void save(Staff staff) {
    staffDao.save(staff);
}

public Staff findByNric(String nric) {
    return staffDao.findByNric(nric);
}

public boolean checkStaffExists(String nric) {
    if (findByNric(nric) != null) return true;
    else return false;
}

@Transactional
public Staff createStaff(Staff staff, Set<StaffRole> staffRoles) {
    Staff localStaff = staffDao.findByNric(staff.getNric());

    if(localStaff != null) {
        LOG.info("Staff with nric {} already exist.", staff.getNric());
    }else {
        String encryptedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(staff.getPassword());
        staff.setPassword(encryptedPassword);

        for(StaffRole sr : staffRoles) {
            roleDao.save(sr.getRole());
        }

        staff.getStaffRoles().addAll(staffRoles);

        localStaff = staffDao.save(staff);
    }

    return localStaff;
}

}
```

StaffService.java

```
package com.ridzuan.service;

import java.util.Set;

import com.ridzuan.domain.Staff;
import com.ridzuan.domain.security.StaffRole;

public interface StaffService {

void save(Staff staff);

Staff findByNric(String nric);

boolean checkStaffExists(String nric);

Staff createStaff(Staff staff, Set<StaffRole> staffRole);
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head th:replace="common/header :: common-header"/>
<body>
<!-- Login Section -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row ">
        <div class="main-center ">
            <div class="bg-danger" th:if="${param.error}">
                Invalid username and password.
            </div>
            <div class="bg-danger" th:if="${param.logout}">
                You have been logged out.
            </div>
            <form class="form-signin" th:action="@{/index}" method="post">
                <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="nric" class="sr-only">NRIC</label>
                    <input type="text" roleId="nric" class="form-control" placeholder="NRIC" name="nric"
                           id="nric"
                           required="required" autofocus="autofocus"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password" class="sr-only">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" roleId="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password"
                           id="password"
                           name="password" required="required"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="remember-me" id="remember-me"/> &nbsp; Remember me
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
            </form>

            <hr />

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div th:replace="common/header :: body-bottom-scripts"/>
```

I insert a log in the StaffSecurityService.java. The console printed out

```
Hibernate: select staff0_.user_id as user_id1_2_, staff0_.is_active as is_activ2_2_, staff0_.nric as nric3_2_, staff0_.password as password4_2_, staff0_.phone as phone5_2_ from staff staff0_ where staff0_.nric=?
2017-09-19 23:54:11.377  INFO 30313 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] c.r.s.S.StaffSecurityService             : NRIC {}, nric
2017-09-19 23:54:11.377  WARN 30313 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] c.r.s.S.StaffSecurityService             : NRIC  not found
```

I inserted a breakpoint loadUserByUsername method in StaffSecurityService.java and staff is null.

Please help, im really stuck. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you check if nric is correct? Also, did you try to execute findAll() method to retrieve all user and then you can check correct nric for your created user.

Comment: Hi yes I've inserted some rows in the db and the nric is correct

Comment: change LOG.info("NRIC {}, nric"); to LOG.info("NRIC {}", nric); to see what is nric
Also, what is result of findAll() method?